# internationalization in input elements in next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, next.js, i18next

I am using i18next package in app which is built using next js. It works fine as long as we use t() from useTranslation hook inside the <h1> or <p>, but on the initial render  t('placeholder') picks up es (spanish) translations which is the fallback language. This causes components like input to display wrong placeholders.

```
<Input
 placeholder={t('placeholder')}
 type="text"
></Input>
```

```
i18n.use(LanguageDetector).init({
  detection: options,
  fallbackLng: 'es',
  resources,
  supportedLngs: ['en', 'es'],
})
```

I loaded the translations files directly in the component and use them like objects EN.placeholder instead of t(''placeholder) and it worked but is there any better way to solve this issue? I guess this is happening because next JS use inbuilt Server Side Rendering

Comment: maybe this explanation helps: https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/1255#issuecomment-864520380

Comment: Are you using [`next-i18next`](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) (it looks like you're not from the code snippets)? If not, have you tried using that instead?